# Update multiple usercontrols with binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, user-controls

I've tried to search, but I can't find the answer. I have a mainwindow containing two usercontrols, A and B. They both have separate ViewModels but get their data from the same modelinstance. When I change a property in usercontrol A, I want it to update the corresponding value in usercontrol B.

It seems that the `OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty")` only updates properties in the same ViewModel. I know that the data behind ViewModel B is the same as for ViewModel A since I can refresh the data manually with a refresh-button.

Are there any simple ways to refresh the values in other usercontrols?

Comment: This is a scenario where you have to synchronise two sources together: you might need http://truss.codeplex.com/

Comment: But the source is the same. Isn't there any way of making PropertyChanged to be application-wide instead of ViewModel-wide?

Answer (score 0):

If you need such behavior also the Model has to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface.

```cs
class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string someText = string.Empty;
    public string SomeText
    {
        get { return this.someText; }
        set { this.someText = value; this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SomeText")); }
    }
}


class ViewModelA : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private Model data;
    public Model Data
    {
        get { return this.data; }
        set { this.data = value; this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Data")); }
    }
}

class ViewModelB : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private Model data;
    public Model Data
    {
        get { return this.data; }
        set { this.data = value; this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Data")); }
    }
}
```

You have to pass the same model instance to both viewmodels and then bind the data in your Controls like this.

For TextBoxA that uses ViewModelA as DataContext

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBoxA" Text="{Binding Path=Data.SomeText}" />
```

For TextBoxB that uses ViewModelB as DataContext

```
<TextBox x:Name="TexTBoxB" Text="{Binding Path=Data.SomeText}" />
```

Now when you Change the text in one of the text boxes it will automatically change in the other.

Comment: This is exactly what I have tried. INotifyPropertChanged is implemented in all classes. I can force it to update with a refresh button, and get the desired result. So I know they use the same instance of that object. It seems that OnPropertyChanged must be called inside ViewModelB for the controls in View B to update.

Comment: I have now tested it again and this definitely works. Maybe it seems, it only works on clicking your Refresh button because then your TextBox looses focus? In General bindings only update when the focus is lost for TextBoxes. So try to set the binding to: Text="{Binding Path=Data.SomeText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}". Maybe this helps.